# Add to array and return array values - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, return

New to coding and this is probably fairly basic, but help would be appreciated.

I believe I have an issue with how I am adding `note2` to `majorScale[]`.  Once the block is finished, it returns `System.String[]` rather than the actual array I was expecting.

```
public static string[] majorScaleOfNote (string tonic)
    {
        string[] intervals = { "M2", "M3", "P4", "P5", "M6", "M7" };
        string[] majorScale = new string[7];
        majorScale [0] = tonic;
        foreach (string interval in intervals) {
            string note2 = intervalUpToNote (tonic, interval);
            majorScale[Array.IndexOf (intervals, interval) + 1] = note2;
        }

        return majorScale;

    }
```

I've narrowed down the problem to something in the `string[] majorScale`.  When I run something without that, it produces the correct result.  Something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine (tonic);
        string[] intervals = { "M2", "M3", "P4", "P5", "M6", "M7" };
        foreach (string interval in intervals) {
            string note2 = intervalUpToNote (tonic, interval);
            Console.WriteLine (note2);
        }
```

Is there an problem with the way I am adding `note2` to `majorScale`?  Or is there another issue?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably not in this method, but in using a result of method execution in a calling method.

I guess, you later try to `Console.WriteLine` the contents of its array like this:

```
string[] result = majorScaleOfNote("M1");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

You cannot output arrays this way.
C# applies `.ToString()` to all objects in order to get their string representation. Arrays do not have its own `ToString()` method, which results in the most base class `Object`'s `.ToString()` being called. It simply does the following:

```
public virtual String ToString()
{ 
    return GetType().ToString(); 
}
```

That's why, it outputs its type which results to `System.String[]`.

If you want to output all elements of an array, you could try to iterate through it yourself and output strings one by one:

```
string[] result = majorScaleOfNote("M1");
foreach (var note in result)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

or you can use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which joins a string using a provided separator:

```
string[] result = majorScaleOfNote("M1");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  I wasn't aware arrays did not have their own `ToString()`.

Both the `foreach` loop and the `String.Join` gave the expected result.

Thanks, Yeldar!